# AWS EC2 - how to make sure an instance is being rebooted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, reboot

I want to issue command (remotely) to reboot EC2 instance and upon successful reboot - need to get confirmation that it was successful. How to achieve this? 
How to know (programmatically) that an EC2 instance was rebooted?

Information to capture needed (similar to these with timestamps if possible):
- reboot attempting 
- reboot started 
- reboot going on 
- reboot completed 
- reboot successful as far as the infrastructure can tell

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to clarify exactly what you mean by "was rebooted"... reboot attempted?  Reboot completed as far as the infrastructure can tell?  Or fully up and all services healthy?  According to the [API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RebootInstances.html), `RebootInstances` always reboots the instance, though how long it takes depends on the instance's stability.

Comment: Great point. It would be great to get all information if possible (reboot attempting, reboot started, reboot going on, reboot completed, reboot successful as far as the infrastructure can tell).

Answer (score 2):

You can poll the instance's status to check the result. Here is some pseudo code which can help you. This is using AWS Java SDK. Process will be similar in other language SDKs.

```
// Call the AWS Ec2 Describe Instance API. 
DescribeInstancesRequest describeRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds("yourInstanceId"); 

DescribeInstancesResult result = ec2Client.describeInstances(describeRequest);

// Fetch the required instance's status. 
InstanceState status = result.getReservations().get(0).getInstances().get(0).getState();

// Check if instance status is Running. 
Objects.equals(status.getName(), InstanceStateName.Running.toString());

// Continue the loop until instance is started running.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to do similar without Java SDK - e.g. with Python or AWS CLI?

Comment: You can do using boto3 in python.

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status -- this would help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled cloudtrail for the region in EC2. Create an metric filter and subscribe to notifications. You will be notified for every reboot.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html#cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail-ec2-instance-changes

Answer (score 0):

Instance state can be checked with the AWS CLI like so.  Make sure to replace YOUR_INSTANCE_ID and YOUR_REGION below.

```bash
aws ec2 describe-instance-status \
  --instance-ids=YOUR_INSTANCE_ID \
  --query='InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceStatus.Status' \
  --region=YOUR_REGION
```

Answer (score 0):

### run "uptime"

connect to machine and run `uptime`

Source https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uptime.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers recommend InstanceStatus. However, that status represents the "instance" status, NOT the status of the OS, i.e. it doesn't change value if you reboot the instance. AFAIK, there is no EC2 API output to check reboot status. As mentioned, you either have to (i) check the machine itself (SSM/script, or some other mechanism), or (ii) look for the CloudWatch event.